# How to Stop triggering Button When user clicks Enter Button React js?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am new to react js,I am little confused that how to stop triggering simple button from triggering when user clicks Enter Button ...
Sorry my code will be Awkward ...... If it is Uncomfortable to Read Feel free to comment it out

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {Link} from 'react-router';
import * as headerAction from '../../Actions/headerActions';
import * as notificationActions from '../../Actions/notificationActions';

import * as tagProfileActions from '../../Actions/tagProfileActions';

class TagProfile extends React.Component{
    static contextTypes = {
        router:React.PropTypes.object
    };
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            data:[],
            tagName:"",
            In:null,
            tagId:"",
            tagFollowers:0,
            isFollowStatus:""

        }
        this.handleFollow =this.handleFollow.bind(this)
    }

    handleFollow(e){
       //How to Prevent this 
        console.log(e.keyCode)//Udefined
        e.preventDefault();
          console.log('Clicked')

    }

    render(){
       console.log(this.state)
        return (
            <div className="ContainerForTagProfile">
                <div className="TagProfileTopSecTion">
                    <h1>Topic: {this.state.tagName} </h1>
                </div>
                <div className="StatusBarRealTimeViewsAndFollowButtn">
                    <div className="ViewCcountBar">
                        <p>30,18,5222    </p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="FollowButtonForTagPRofile">
                        <button type="button"  onClick={(e)=>this.handleFollow(e)}>{this.state.tagFollowers} | {this.state.isFollowStatus}</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="GallerySectionForTagforfile">


                    {this.state.data.map(data => {

                        return (
                            <Link key={data.id} href="#" target="_blank" to={'/'+data.postId}><div  className="SingleImagePost">
                                <img src={data.thumNailUrl} />
                                <div className="LiveViewCountBar">
                                    <p>{data.views}   - {data.whoLikedIt.length} ❤</p>
                                </div>
                                <div className="LikesBar">
                                    <div className="MakeItCenter">
                                        <div className="ProfileTinyImage">
                                            <img src={data.postOwnerPic} />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="ProfilePosTOwnerName">
                                            <p>{data.postOwnerFullName}</p>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div></Link>
                        )
                    })}


                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        isLoggedIn:state.logInStatus
    }
};
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        getTagProfileData:(slug) => dispatch(tagProfileActions.getTagDetails(slug)),
        getTagFollowInfo:slug => dispatch(tagProfileActions.getTagFollowInfo(slug)),
        toogleSignInOut:bool => dispatch(headerAction.toggleSignPop(bool)),
        popErrorNotification:(bool,color,message) => dispatch(notificationActions.popUpNotification(bool,color,message)),
        tagProfileFollow:(data) => dispatch(tagProfileActions.tagProfileFollow(data))

    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(TagProfile)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got Solution
   Just added KeyDown and Onclick Evt And Throwed some if else statement for KeyBoard Events..

```
 handleFollow(e){
            e.preventDefault()
            if(e.type !== 'keydown'){
                //Start Code From here
               }

        }
```