# RestartClicked() is being called when it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

I'm making this tic tac toe project for school, and at first I made a tic tac toe game which worked completely and worked by using my mouse. Currently I'm trying to make it work with arrow keys, and it works completely when I start the page/refresh. But whenever I press the restart button, which resets all values to what they were at start, the enter button just randomly resets the position of where the red box is, and also resets all the values added by it to that specific spot. Because it outputs the array with one value filled in and then the next enter does the exact same.

Could anyone help find a solution to what's causing the problem, because every way of debugging hasn't worked yet.

The function using the keys:

```
function keyDown(e) {
    console.log(e.keyCode);

    let prevBox = boxes[prevActive];
    prevBox.style.backgroundColor = "";


    switch (e.keyCode) {
        //right arrow key
        case 39:
            xPos = xPos < 2 ? xPos + 1 : xPos = 0;

            break;
        //left arrow key
        case 37:
            xPos = xPos > 0 ? xPos - 1 : xPos = 2;

            break;
        // down arrow key
        case 40:
            yPos = yPos < 2 ? yPos + 1 : yPos = 0;
 
            break;
        // up arrow key
        case 38:
            yPos = yPos > 0 ? yPos - 1 : yPos = 0;
            break;

    }
    console.log([xPos, yPos]);
    
    active = yPos * 3 + xPos;
    redBox = boxes[active].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    
    console.log(active);
    
    prevActive = active;
    prevBox = boxes[prevActive];

    if (e.keyCode == 13) {

        if(!spaces[active]) {
            spaces[active] = currentPlayer;
            boxes[active].innerText = currentPlayer;

            currentPlayer = currentPlayer == letterX ? letterO : letterX;

            if (winner() !== false) {
                playerText = `${currentPlayer} has won!`
        
                let winCombo = winner();
        
                console.log(winCombo);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Restart Button function:

```
restartBtn.addEventListener('click', restartClicked);

function restartClicked() {
    spaces.fill(null);

    boxes.forEach( box => {
        box.innerText = '';

        box.style.backgroundColor = "";
    });

    boxes[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    active = 0;
    prevActive = 0;

    xPos = 0; yPos = 0;

    currentPlayer = letterX
}

startGame();
```

HTML File:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1 id="tictactoe">Tic Tac Toe</h1>
            <button id="restartBtn">Restart</button>

            <div id="gameTable">
                <div class="box" id="0"></div>
                <div class="box" id="1"></div>
                <div class="box" id="2"></div>
                <div class="box" id="3"></div>
                <div class="box" id="4"></div>
                <div class="box" id="5"></div>
                <div class="box" id="6"></div>
                <div class="box" id="7"></div>
                <div class="box" id="8"></div>
            </div>

            <h1 id="currentPlayerTxt"></h1>

            <script src="index2.js"></script>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

CSS file:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Nunito';
  src: url('Fonts/Nunito-Regular.ttf');
}


html, body {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Nunito';
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #c2415d;
}

  
.boxContainer {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 400px;
  height: 450px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.boxBtn {
  font-size: 50px;
  background-color:rgb(255, 0, 0);
  line-height: 60px;
  width: 60%;
  font-size: 24px;
  user-select: none;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit
}

#tictactoe {
  color: #ffffff;
}

#gameTable {
  width: 450px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: 40px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.box { 
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 120px;
  outline: 2px solid;
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
  user-select: none;
}

.box:nth-child(6) ~ .box {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

I was expecting it to just result into doing the same thing as it did at the start of the document, updating the values to keep the red spot in the right place, and not for the enter button to have a behavior it shouldn't have.

Comment: Restart button is set, like these others
let ticTacToe = document.getElementById("tictactoe");
let restartBtn = document.getElementById("restartBtn");
let boxes = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("box"));

Comment: Initially when using my program on a fresh page it works, but after pressing this button it does reset everything, but enter keeps triggering it for some reason, btw enter's keycode is 13

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Stop triggering Button When user clicks Enter Button React js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41493237/how-to-stop-triggering-button-when-user-clicks-enter-button-react-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the issue. It was due to enter causing the button to be activated, and my input for placing down an X or an O was enter. I activated blur on the button and it removed all keyboard focus on the element.

So for anyone having this dumb issue in the future, I hope I helped you all.